# How to fix 'Distance is not printed on monitor'?

Tags: c

My collage mate and I have homework for programming. We need to create a "reversing radar" with a HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor on a Raspberry Pi.

Our problem is the next: we don't see the 'distance' variable printed on the monitor.

We tried to make a variable inside main(), but still no respond. 
We even tried to make it in Python where it works properly (No we can't do in Python because our teacher wants it in C.).
I copied a program from the internet, and that is not working neither.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define TRIG 5
#define ECHO 6

void setup() {
        wiringPiSetup();
        pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);

        //TRIG pin must start LOW
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
        delay(30);
}

int getCM() {
        //Send trig pulse
        digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(20);
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

        //Wait for echo start
        while(digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);

        //Wait for echo end
        long startTime = micros();
        while(digitalRead(ECHO) == HIGH);
        long travelTime = micros() - startTime;

        //Get distance in cm
        int distance = travelTime / 58;

        return distance;
}

int main(void) {
        setup();

        printf("Distance: %dcm\n", getCM());

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you even connect it to the correct pins? Then you need to debug the program to find out what is happening there and where it hangs. Try adding for example debug prints or running in a debugger.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_we don't see the 'distance' variable printed _"?  Is anything printed?  Are you perhaps running this program from an IDE or from a GUI environment?  If so the problem is that your program runs to completion and terminates, when a process terminates, the OS will close its window - so you never see the output.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala We tried to print out the distance variable in the getCM function but no output. If you have any tip what should we looking for while debugging please tell me.

Comment: @Clifford 
In main() we used printf to print out the distance variable on screen. After i start the program it runs properly but we dont see the distance, its like the printf "not working". 
Im using Linux and just compile the file every time when i change something on it ( i know its not the best but im programming on a Raspberry Pi ).

Comment: @teddy : It sounds  more like the `getCM()` function is not returning - see my answer.  Have you verified the wait for echo loop actually terminates?  You should as soon as possible learn how to use a debugger such as GDB so you can really see what is happening rather than guessing (although it is somewhat user-hostile in its raw form. Easier used in some IDE such as Code::Blocks which runs fine of a RPi if a bit slow on my first edition board!  Failing that put a print before and after the while loop to see whether it gets that far, and whether it even gets an echo.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCM()` function has a potentially endless loop waiting for an echo.  If your hardware is not working correctly or there is no object in range with a sufficiently string reflection, `getCM()` will never exit.

You should have a timeout in `getCM()`.  For example if you want a maximum range of say three meters, the maximum time to echo will be about 18ms - i.e. (distance x 2) / *speed-of-sound*.  After that you need to give up and send another ping:

Given :

```
#define MIN_RANGE_CM 4
#define MAX_RANGE_METRES 3
#define SPEED_OF_SOUND_M_PER_SEC 343
#define MAX_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US (MAX_RAMGE_METRES * 2000000) / SPEED_OF_SOUND_M_PER_SEC
#define MIN_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US (MAX_RAMGE_CM * 20000) / SPEED_OF_SOUND_M_PER_SEC
```

Your `getCM()` might look like:

```
int getCM() 
{
    int distance = -1 ;
    long startTime = micros() ;
    long elapsed_time = 0 ;

    // Send ping pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

    // Wait for ping end
    while( digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW && 
           elapsed_time < MIN_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US )
    {
        elapsed_time = micros() - startTime ;
    }

    // If not timed out waiting...
    if( elapsed_time < MIN_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US )
    {
        // Wait for echo
        elapsed_time = 0 ;
        while( digitalRead(ECHO) == HIGH && 
               elapsed_time < MAX_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US )
        {
            elapsed_time = micros() - startTime ;
        }

        // If not timed out, get distance in cm
        if( elapsed_time < MAX_TIME_OF_FLIGHT_US )
        {
            distance = (elapsed_time * SPEED_OF_SOUND_M_PER_SEC) / 20000 ;
        }
    }

    return distance ; 
}
```

Note that each loop has a timeout.  Note also that your comments and timing did not seem correct.  You are waiting for end of the ping and the start of the echo, not the start and end of the echo. The time of flight is the period from the *start* of the ping, to the *first* detected echo.  Your implementation does not start timing until the *end* of the ping.  In your case a 20us ping is only a few millimetres, so it probably does not matter.  The implementation above uses a "minimum range" as a timeout for waiting for the end of the ping - arbitrarily 5cm - if the input has not gone low in that time there is an issue - hardware fault or someone jangling their keys (that can really mess up an ultrasonic sensor - try it!).

For this application your distance will need to be measured continuously.  To that end I suggest:

```
int main(void) 
{
    setup();

    for( ;; )
    {
        printf( "Distance: " ) ;

        int distance = getCM() ;
        if( distance >= 0 )
        {
            printf( "%dcm        \r", distance ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Out-of-range\r" ) ;
        }

        fflush( stdout ) ;
        delay( 200 ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `\r` will reuse the same line to display the distance, preventing the terminal from scrolling.  The space padding ensures the previous output is overwritten.  The `fflush()` call ensures that buffered output is output immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I found the potential problem. 
The distance in the getCM() function was an integer but we divide the number by 58.
I think if i divide a number with 58 wont be an integer. 
I changed it to double and now it works.

Comment: @teddy : your fix does not explain why it was not printing and if the time is in microseconds the integer division is sufficiently accurate for centimetre resolution.  So your explanation of the issue does not stand up.  There is no need to resort to float in any event.